# Linking sharepoint to access-Permissions

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I'm currently creating a sharepoint(2013) website whilst linking it to an access database. When I link the sharepoint in the access and try to modify the fields it says it's ready only. Where can I change permissions? I tried fumbling around sharepoint for permissions however nothing seems to work also the access file itself is not read only.

Comment: Are you trying to modify field content or field properties (table design)?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm trying to create a Primary key and also foreign keys in access since I haven't found a way to do it in sharepoint to link lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the table design of external tables using Access.

This is not a permission issue. It's just not something that Access can do.

Comment: Is there a way to link lists together like access's relationships? The only thing I could find is the "lookup" field however it's not ideal for use.

Comment: You can use relationships, because these don't influence the table design. You just can't enforce relationships and set constraints, because those do. You can use lookup fields on forms, and use queries to link things together.